# When I try to query child elements within connectedCallback, I get an empty nodelist

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

```html
<script>
  class SomeClass extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      // returns empty nodelist
      console.log(this.querySelectorAll('.thing'));
    }

  }

  customElements.define('my-component', SomeClass);
</script>

<my-component>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
</my-component>
```

When I try to query child elements within connectedCallback, I get an empty nodelist.

If I move `script` tag after `<my-component>` - it starts working:

```html
<my-component>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
</my-component>

<script>
  class SomeClass extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      // returns empty nodelist
      console.log(this.querySelectorAll('.thing'));
    }

  }

  customElements.define('my-component', SomeClass);
</script>
```

Is there some callback that triggers when all child elements are available? (no matter where `<script>` was added). Do I really have to use something like document.ready or mutation observer? What's the most efficient way?

Comment: This fiddle has the script in the `<head>` and works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/drb97me2/

Comment: I'm testing this on Firefox. Chrome indeed does things differently. But yeah, the solution is to use a DOM ready event.

Comment: @LGSon how is this a duplicate? it's totally unrelated issue, since when web components require document.ready.

Comment: If you try to access an element with a script where the script runs _before_ the elements been parsed/DOM ready, always, hence this being a duplicate, and its answers explains that.

Comment: @LGSon that is understandable, but how does your "duplicate" thread answer the question for web components that can be added dynamically any time?

Comment: It doesn't, but you don't ask about that, you ask _"When I try to query child elements within connectedCallback, I get an empty nodelist."_, and with the given sample, it is a duplicate. If you need to know about dynamically added components, you need to post a question/sample that does that, though if the logic in such sample is the same as in this, it will as well fail for the same reason.

Comment: @LGSon I'm sorry for chosing incorrect title, I edited it.

Comment: Found the reason, reopened and posted an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a 'connectedCallback' for when all child custom elements have been connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663678/how-to-have-a-connectedcallback-for-when-all-child-custom-elements-have-been-c)

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be a different behavior between browsers, where it works on e.g. Firefox, but Chrome (Blink) need "Mutation Observers".

- https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/551

---

Optionally one can place the script after the component, for the same reason DOM work in general.

- [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

---

Or make the `customElements.define()` call after DOM been loaded

```html
<script>
  class SomeClass extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      // returns empty nodelist
      console.log(this.querySelectorAll('.thing'));
    }

  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    customElements.define('my-component', SomeClass);
  });
</script>

<my-component>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
</my-component>
```